# how to transition on page load

Tags: css, animation

So I have been able to have an image rotate on hover, but I would like to have it rotate on page load. I have tried everything I could find to try try it but with no luck. I have kind-of pieced the following together from what I have read from some other sources but I have no idea and am a beginner.

```
.spin-logo {
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg)
  -webkit-transition: transform 5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  from {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg)}
  to {-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need two things

1. Add the spinner html to your page
2. Remove the  spinner after page load

you can remove the spiner using javascript or fade it out using javascript

```
function RemoveSpinner() {
    $(".spin-logo").remove();
}

$(window).load(function() 
{
  RemoveSpinner();
});
```

or

```
 function FadeOutSpinner() {
        $(".spin-logo").fadeOut();
    }

    $(window).load(function() 
    {
      FadeOutSpinner();
    });
```